# Unable to block incoming call in Android

Tags: java, android

Calling this method in my Receiver class that extend  BroadcastReceiver to cancel incoming call.There is no error in code at compile time but when this method is called the exception is thrown that is.

**Exception**

java.lang exception android.content.context.getsystemservice(java.lang.string)' on a null object reference

**Code**

```
 private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context)
{
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try
    {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is in the message. Your Context is null. Can you share your entire class please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you properly forward the `Context` to your method. It seems that the context somehow gets lost during `public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)`

To properly answer this, please show the entire class and make sure that `disconnectPhoneItelephony()` is called with the correct `Context` instance.